AWS Elastic Beanstalk error on upload and redeploy
Can't upload and redeploy a new version of the application. Getting message
"Error when trying to upload and deploy new version to the environment
Changes to option DisableIMDSv1 settings will not take effect immediately. Each of your existing EC2 instances will be replaced and your new settings will take effect then.".
Tried to restart the server, reboot the ec2 instance, and detach and attach a new ec2 instance. None of these options helped. Please note that I haven't changed any configuration since elb instance was created. And redeployed my application in this way.
[UPDATE]
I found a solution, unchecking Deactivated from the Environment configuration,

however, after the long update, I need to target newly created instance from the load balancer. So I want to get a clear explanation of why it happened and how to prevent it from happening again.

Does your Elastic Beanstalk platform version support both IMDSv1 and IMDSv2?

@ArpitJain after unchecking it starts work as expected. Image: [https://imgur.com/vVR0Oi5]

not able to view the image, pls add it inline in the question.

Why this sudden error we are facing, in last week it was working fine. Something might have changed from AWS site

@Djai I think so, next days it works fine, and what I noticed, that the window where uploading new version package, that time was changed (the section All at once gone ) but now it's back and everything working fine

@AlexandrSargsyan, Yes looks like, it started working for me as well now

I don't know what this means but I came across the same error. So here is a work around:

In the menu, go to "application versions"
Upload your project
Select the uploaded project and choose "deploy" in "actions"


Thanks for your reply. Will check next time!

This worked for me today.  Note that the deploy step doesn't show the green completed banner at top of page so you need to read the Info messages instead.

I would not prefer this because i have 2 environments and i just wanted to update one of them
